# ruby aws-sdk multi-part upload doesn't honor requested storage class "STANDARD_IA"

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm uploading fairly large objects (~500 MB) using the v2 aws-sdk gem as follows:

```
object = bucket.object("#{prefix}/#{object_name}")
raise RuntimeError, "failed to upload: #{object_name}" unless object.upload_file("#{object_name}", storage_class: "STANDARD_IA")
```

The uploads succeed and I can see the new objects in the console, but they all have a storage class of "Standard".

When I run this same code with smaller objects they're correctly created with storage class = "STANDARD_IA".

Is this a factor of the file size?  Or the fact that it's a multi-part upload?  Or something else?  I didn't see anything in the documentation, but its pretty "expansive" so I may just have missed it.

Comment: the multipart cutoff is at 15 MB. Can you confirm that's where you see this behavior? Also: what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I will run a test to see if multi-part is the relevant factor.  I'm using the latest version of the gem: 2.2.20.  Ruby is 2.1.5.

Comment: Yes, size seems to be the deciding factor.  A 16M file was stored as "Standard" while a 1K file was stored as "Standard - Infrequent Access".  Is that a feature or a bug?

Comment: look like a bug. I would enable logging (see https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx35LF8S4I1BICE/Logging-Requests)  to see if the SDK does the right thing and it's S3 that does not behave in case of multipart uploads using IA or it's the SDK that screws up making the requests

Comment: as an alternative, if you don't care that much about this, you could just raise the multipart_threshold as documented here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#upload_file-instance_method

Comment: Thanks.  I created an issue at GitHub; hopefully someone will take a look at it.  Some of the files I'm uploading are very large (~1GB), so raising the threshold wouldn't help in all cases.  Will try with logging and report back.

Comment: With debug on I can see that the "storage_class" parameter is completely absent from the "create_multipart_upload", "upload_part" and "complete_multipart_upload" calls.  So, bug.  If I can figure out how to fix it I'll just create a pull request.

Comment: Pull request submitted.  Was a one-liner.  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/pull/1108

Answer (score 1):

Was caused by a bug in aws-sdk-ruby.  Pull request:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/pull/1108

Comment: awesome. actually looked at the code, but not the part this. how did you find this?

Comment: I just worked backwards from the "upload_file" method.  I don't actually understand how this part works: "Client.api.operation(:upload_part).input.shape.member_names", but it seemed suspicious that both "CREATE_OPTIONS" and "UPLOAD_PART_OPTIONS" used ":upload_part".  So I figured it was a cut/paste error.